# Why do runtime APIs have a block_height parameter on the client side but not on the runtime side?

Tags: macro, runtime-api

Runtime APIs are declared using the [`decl_runtime_api!` macro](https://crates.parity.io/sp_api/macro.decl_runtime_apis.html). This is typically in a primitives crate. For example:

```
decl_runtime_apis! {
    pub trait ExampleApi {
        fn get_info(param1: u32, param2: u32) -> bool;
    }
```

Then they are implemented with the [`impl_runtime_api!` macro](https://crates.parity.io/sp_api/macro.impl_runtime_apis.html). This is in the Runtime. Continuing the example:

```
impl_runtime_apis! {
    impl ExampleApi<Block> for Runtime {
        fn get_info(param1: u32, param2: u32) -> bool {
            param1 == param2
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, they can be called from client side. Here there are no macros used, but there is an additional parameter for the block at which the call should be made. Completing the example:

```
let block_to_call_at = BlockId::Hash(parent.hash());
client.runtime_api().get_info(&block_to_call_at, 5, 10)
```

**Question**: Where is the machinery that handles the block height parameter, and passes the remaining parameters into the wasm runtime? Is this handled in the macros? When writing a runtime in a non-Rust language, does one need to reproduce any logic from the macros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block hash is for client-side rather than the runtime itself - it tells the client to invoke the runtime API using the post-state of the given block hash. The way this manifests is in how the client, which hosts the runtime, answers host functions called by the runtime Wasm as it executes. Most notably, it affects the host functions pertaining to storage. The client also selects and executes the runtime Wasm code which was available as-of the post-state of the given block.

The actual generated Wasm ABI for the runtime API functions doesn't accept the block hash as a parameter. This means that if you write a runtime without using FRAME, it will still be compatible with the Substrate client's runtime API system as long as the ABI of the exposed functions is consistent.

The `impl_runtime_apis` macro also implements [`ProvideRuntimeApis`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_api/trait.ProvideRuntimeApi.html) for the Client, when the runtime is compiled for native and linked into the node binary itself. This internal implementation detail is likely to change when the native runtime is no longer required by Substrate. Currently, it [generates a wrapper](https://crates.parity.io/src/sp_api_proc_macro/impl_runtime_apis.rs.html#331) around anything which implements [`CallApiAt`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_api/trait.CallApiAt.html), which is a trait implemented for every `Client`.